# Java Script: assign var in function and use var out that function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var statustext="test";
$zack(function() {
  $zack.setOnStatus(changelable);
});
function changelable(status) {
  if (status=='A')
    statustext="OK";
  else if (status=='B')
    statustext="Ready";
  else if (status=='C')
    statustext="Go";
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = statustext; // OK, Ready or Go
}
</script>
```

`document.getElementById('title').innerHTML` shows *OK, Ready or Go*.

But when I use this script somewhere below the above script the `statustext` variable contains *test* text as pre assigned:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('title2').innerHTML = statustext; // test
</script>
```

I want to use `statustext` with *OK, Ready or Go* text multiple times. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `title2` code runs *right away* when the page is loaded, but your other code runs in response to an event (the status change event or whatever that calls `changelable`).

If you want to set `title2` to the same thing you're setting `title` to, move this line:

```
document.getElementById('title2').innerHTML = statustext;
```

...*into* the `changelable` function, just after this line:

```
document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = statustext;
```

e.g.:

```
document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = statustext;
document.getElementById('title2').innerHTML = statustext;
```

or if you like:

```
document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = document.getElementById('title2').innerHTML = statustext;
```

---

Separately, your `if/else if/else if` sequence is really what the `switch` statement is for:

```
function changelable(status) {
  switch (status) {
    case 'A':
      statustext="OK";
      break;
    case 'B':
      statustext="Ready";
      break;
    case 'C':
      statustext="Go";
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = statustext;
  document.getElementById('title2').innerHTML = statustext;
}
```

Or you could use a lookup table:

```
var statustext="test";
var statusLabels = {
    A: "OK",
    B: "Ready",
    C: "GO"
};
$zack(function() {
  $zack.setOnStatus(changelable);
});
function changelable(status) {
  statustext = statusLabels[status] || statustext;
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = statustext;
  document.getElementById('title2').innerHTML = statustext;
}
```